# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating Helloworld in PHP by following the tutorials given in [net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/](http://goo.gl/mOto). Following is the controller code which is creating the error:

```
<?php  
class Helloworld extends Controller{  
    function index()  
    {  
        $this->load->model('helloworld_model');  

        $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql">getData</span>();  
        $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";  

        $this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);  
    }  
}   ?>
```

Any help?

Comment: Ok, this is from a tutorial that many people read, so cannot be localized

Answer (score 1):

There was a rendering error on the page you visited.  An HTML tag was being displayed when it shouldn't have been.  Here is the fixed line:

```
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData();
```

Comment: Now I am getting this - Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found?

Comment: @Arun Follow the tutorial... don't try to skip ahead.

Comment: @Arun, if you are using Codeigniter 2.0 or later, use `CI_Controller` instead of `Controller`.